# Serilog does not output logs into the txt file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, backgroundworker, serilog

Im using dotnet worker service (.net 5)
I integrated serilog as well as enrichers and sinks.
But for some reason I dont see any outputs into my files logs.

Here is my appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.;Database=eeee;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "WorkerOptions": {
    "Batch": 5
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "E:\\Logs\\log_.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "E:\\Logs\\log_.json",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Registration of logger:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                            .CreateLogger();

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {

                var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                                            .Build();

                var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>(s => new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options));
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
}
```

and this is an implementation:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
     _logger.LogInformation("Worker picked up {0} requests for dispatch at at: {time}", generatedRequests.Count(), DateTimeOffset.Now);
    }
```

And when I run the worker through Kestrel I can see in my console logs, but not in my .txt file nor .json file

**UPDATE #1**
I tried with this answer below, but I still have an issue when I deploy my worker, I do not see any logs.
When I run it thrpugh service.exe fi;le or just do debugg (Kestrel) Logs files are generated.

Here is updated application.json:

```
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [],
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
  "WriteTo": [
    { "Name": "Console" },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": ".\\Logs\\log_.txt",
        "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
        "rollingInterval": "Day",
        "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": ".\\Logs\\log_.json",
        "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
        "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
        "rollingInterval": "Day",
        "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is the Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                            .CreateLogger();

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseWindowsService()
                    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                    {

                        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
                        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                        services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>(s => new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options));
                        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    })
                    .UseSerilog(); // no args
}
```

**UPDATE#2**
I updated Program class like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseWindowsService()
                    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                    {

                        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
                        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                        services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>(s => new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options));
                        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    })
                    .UseSerilog((hostContext, services, logger) => {
                        logger.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostContext.Configuration);
                    });
    }
}
```

Also I put simple stuff in appsettings.json:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": { "path": "Logs/log.txt" }
      },
      //{
      //  "Name": "File",
      //  "Args": {
      //    "path": ".\\Logs\\log_.txt",
      //    "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
      //    "rollingInterval": "Day",
      //    "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
      //  }
      //},
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": ".\\Logs\\log_.json",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here is the also call of the _logger which is working, agaion when I start .exe file (console)

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
...
private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
...
_logger.LogInformation("Worker picked up {0} requests for dispatch at: {time}", generatedRequests.Count(), DateTimeOffset.Now);
```

**UPDATE#3**
I just setup absolute path for logging `c:\\Logs\log.txt` and it works partially - it creates a txt file, but file is empty.
Here is the new appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.;Database=svcProcessor_dev;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "WorkerOptions": {
    "Batch": 10,
    "Delay": 5000,
    "MaxAttempts":  3
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File"],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": { "path": "C:\\Logs\\log.txt" }
      }
      //{
      //  "Name": "File",
      //  "Args": {
      //    "path": "C:\\Logs\\log_.txt",
      //    "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
      //    "rollingInterval": "Day",
      //    "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
      //  }
      //}
      //{
      //  "Name": "File",
      //  "Args": {
      //    "path": "C:\\Logs\\log_.json",
      //    "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
      //    "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
      //    "rollingInterval": "Day",
      //    "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
      //  }
      //}
    ]
  }
}
```

**update#4**

Here is the minimal example of my worker
[worker example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1honajjzH6WDybUZ7yHdJ3wVWsc__7_6U/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Might be stupid question, but have you checked folder permissions? The executing process will need write access to `E:\logs`

Comment: yes, I cheked. Also, I tried to change to root folder of an app `.\\Logs\log_.txt`

Comment: Try using async writer. I know this sounds ridiculous but there are some cases where invoking logger in same thread will not work for logging adapters (UseSerilog).

Comment: How you deploy your app on linux machine? docker or some other approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't adding the infrastructure to convert Serilog's `Logger` into a `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`. As it stands, you are are just creating the Serilog Logger but not actually using it. What you're seeing in the console are actually the logs from the built-in Microsoft logger and *not* from Serilog.

Fortunately Serilog has an adapter from their logger to the Microsoft logger interfaces and various helper packages depending on your usage scenario. You're using the Generic Host so first add the [`Serilog.Extensions.Hosting` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Extensions.Hosting/) to your project. Then call the `UseSerilog` extension method. The delegate passed to this method receives an instance of the `HostBuilderContext` from which you can retrieve the current `IConfiguration` as well as the `IServiceProvider` and a `LoggingConfiguration` you use to configure the logger:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
   Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)              
       .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
           /* elided */
        })
       .UseSerilog((hostContext, services, logger) => {
            logger.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostContext.Configuration);
        });
```

Note that there's no longer a need to set the `Log.Logger` property and build a `LoggerConfiguration` directly from within `Main`. The `UseSerilog` method will set the static logger automatically--though you won't need it, you're logging via `ILogger<>` anyways.

Alternatively, you *can* configure the logger way you do currently (directly in `Main`). If you go this route you would call `UseSerilog` without any parameters. This will in turn use the current configuration of the static logger.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                        .Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggingConfiguration()
                        .ReadFromConfiguration(config)
                        .CreateLogger();

    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
   Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)              
       .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
           /* elided */
        })
       .UseSerilog(); // no args
```

Personally I don't like this option, especially when using `ReadFrom.Configuration` as it requires you to build an extra configuration object. I'd prefer to use the one passed in to the callback since it will match all other configuration used by the Host.

#### ASP.NET Core

You tagged your question with `aspnet-core` and refer to "Kestrel" in your question. However the code you demonstrated shows a pretty basic Generic Host and *not* a web application. If this *really* is a web application then you would add the [`Serilog.AspNetCore` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.AspNetCore) instead. That package implicitly references  `Serilog.Extensions.Hosting` and includes some other bits and pieces for use from within a web application.

Comment: I still cant see any logs. When I start Kestrel, logs are there, but soon as I publish my app and register service, and do start service, I do not receive any logs (Logs folder isn't created)

Comment: You need to fill in the "Using" property in your AppSettings.json with the names of the sinks to use. Check Serilog github for examples. It's not enough that you have them listed under WriteTo, their assembly names have to be listed. Also I really wouldn't suggest using the No-Argument version of UseSerilog there's some downsides to it. Use the way I showed first and ditch anything about the static logger

Comment: There's examples right here: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#serilogsettingsconfiguration--

Comment: @Stefan0309 Also how are you publishing your application? Is it single-file publish? If so, there's some other things you have to do to get it to work in addition to adding the Using property

Comment: still the same, after I added using part in appsettings.json

Comment: here is my screenshot of my publish configuration: https://i.imgur.com/ZKOHxHu.png

Comment: How many files does it generate? Just one Exe and the config files? Or Exe plus dlls?

Comment: but I have weird behavior with service itself https://i.imgur.com/qRYtXCM.png I can click on start service button, but it says in my services thats already running..?

Comment: I just noticed your paths are relative. They are probably logging into System32 or some weird place depending on how you deploy. Try putting an absolute (full) path for testing purposes to a folder that the user has write access to (create like "c:/logs" for example and use that in your config). It's important you make sure it has full access permissions for everyone, at least for debugging purposes.

Comment: I don't have an answer for that. Sorry. That's a different question, I'd suggest opening a new one. But I guarantee your logs are somewhere under System32 folder since you are running as a service and you are using relative paths. Services typically run with a working directory of system32 and I recall a similar question on this site recently where that was true for another user

Comment: And make sure you are setting the log path correctly. In your AppSettings.json you set it two different ways to two different paths. I'm not sure which one is the correct way, so I'd just set them both to the same full path for now

Comment: Please, see my update#3 in my question. Now it creates file on `C:\Logs\log.txt` as you mentioned but it's empty. If I add outputTemplate, file is still empty.

Comment: Please see my update #4 - I uploaded minimal working example of my worker. When I start service, it creates C:\Logs\log.txt file but its empty..

Comment: I've got your example locally but I don't have time to review it right now. I did notice that you still don't have the values under "using" in the files you provide in the zip. Also, I didn't realize this before when I made a previous comment, but you have TWO file sinks set up and they are both writing to the same place. I would suggest either removing one  of them or changing one of the paths. It's possible they are fighting for the same file.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I was having a similar issue where my log file was not being written to in my .Net 5 application. As @pinkfloydx33 asked several times above, are you publishing this application as a single file application? In my case, I am doing so. In the link he shared and the reason he was asking, is because there is something specific you need to do in .Net 5 single file applications and that is the "Using" statement in your appsettings.json. .Net 5 single file applications cannot resolve the namespaces for you so you must specify them in the "Using" statement.

Here is the article he shared: [Serilog configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#serilogsettingsconfiguration--)

And here is the specific section dealing with .Net 5 single file applications: [Serilog single file applications](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#net-50-single-file-applications)

Once I simply added my using for "Serilog.Sinks.File" to my appsettings.json, my logger started writing to the file.

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I've seen when working with serilog(I apologize if they are mentioned above and I missed them).

The AppSettings will override one another if you have several per environment.
Sometimes depending on how you are logging your output you may want to consider changing the logging level. Debug or Verbose

One last thing is in your worker, instead of the ms logging extension switch it to using serilog, that should cause your logging to have to be done using _log.Information("SampleEntry") which is serilogs pipe

And as mentioned above in the appsetting you'll want to have
"Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File"]  and maybe even "Serilog.Settings.Configuration" for custom config stuff