# Serilog logs to console, but not to file or database

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

I'm creating a web API with ASP.NET Core, but I'm having some trouble getting Serilog to work. It will output to the console fine. However, when I tell it to output to a file, it will create a file, but not enter any logs into it. The same happens when I try to use a PostgreSQL database. Any ideas on what is wrong?

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Serilogs\\AppLogs.log"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "PostgreSQL",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Server=fake_server;Port=5432;Database=filter_endpoints;User Id=postgres;Password=fake_password;",
          "tableName": "Logs",
          "needAutoCreateTable": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

**Startup.cs**

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

             Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().
              Enrich.FromLogContext().
              ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).
              CreateLogger();


            Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
        }
```

**Edit**
I got it to work with the file. Apparently, I had had a second block of configuring code like the one in Startup.cs in Program.cs. I took it out, and it is now righting to the file.

I'm still having some trouble with getting it to work with the database, though. I added that into the sample code. I replaced some values in the connection string with sample values for security. I know the connection string is good since the database table was created.

**Edit**
I finally got this to work. I did have a slight problem with my code. I believe I should have been using the Serilog.Syncs.PostgrSQL.Configuration package on top of the mail PostgreSQL package. I'm not sure if that was a contribution factor or not.

The main problem was that for some reason the sync did not work with the latest versions of NpgSQL (I found that in a Github issue for the sync). I downgraded NpgSQL for now. Hopefully they get that fixed soon.

Thank you to everyone who tried to help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serilog does not output logs into the txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67300156/serilog-does-not-output-logs-into-the-txt-file)

Comment: See the link. You're doing it wrong

Comment: File writing works, so I doubt that's the problem, but I guess its a possibility.

Comment: Well I still submit that you're using it wrong. You should add the Serilog hosting project and make sure to add the ILogger services. Also, you've not shown your AppSettings.development.json file. It's possible you're overwriting values from it. Oh and, since youre doing it wrong, you need to forcibly call Log.CloseAndFlush otherwise you're not guaranteed the messages make it and that actually sounds like your empty file issue

Comment: Thanks for you help. I plan to try that out tomorrow.

Comment: My appsettings.development.json is identical to my appsettings.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this to work. I did have a slight problem with my code. I believe I should have been using the Serilog.Syncs.PostgrSQL.Configuration package on top of the mail PostgreSQL package. I'm not sure if that was a contribution factor or not.

The main problem was that for some reason the sync did not work with the latest versions of NpgSQL (I found that in a Github issue for the sync). I downgraded NpgSQL for now. Hopefully they get that fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to tell Serilog which sinks it should use? :-)

`"Using":  [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],`

From Serilog documentation: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#serilogsettingsconfiguration--

Comment: I had not done that for the console or file syncs, but I had for the database. For some reason, the console worked and the database didn't, so I presume that wasn't the problem.

Comment: Serilog will sometimes detect the sinks properly, if it can find the appropriate dlls in the correct places. But not always. The official guidance is to always include the Using property when reading from configuration